# Error creating a connection to Postgresql while preparing konga database

Tags: postgresql, kong, konga

After installing Konga, we are trying to prepare Konga database on the already running Postgresql database. by using suggested command i.e.

```
node ./bin/konga.js prepare --adapter postgres --uri postgresql://localhost:5432/konga
```

But we are facing the error as below:

```
Error creating a connection to Postgresql using the following settings:
 postgresql://localhost:5432/konga?host=localhost&port=5432&schema=true&ssl=false&adapter=sails-postgresql&user=postgres&password=XXXX&database=konga_database&identity=postgres

* * *
Complete error details:
 error: password authentication failed for user "root"
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Failed to prepare database: error: password authentication failed for user "root"
```

We even created the schema konga_database manually and have tried several variations for prepare command but no fate

```
node ./bin/konga.js  prepare --adapter postgres --uri postgresql://kong:XXXX@localhost:5432/konga_database
node ./bin/konga.js  prepare --adapter postgres --uri postgresql://kong@localhost:5432/konga
node ./bin/konga.js  prepare --adapter postgres --uri postgresql://kong@localhost:5432/konga_database
```

Below is config/connections.js

```
  postgres: {
    adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
    url: process.env.DB_URI,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost',
    user:  process.env.DB_USER || 'postgres',
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'XXXX',
    port: process.env.DB_PORT || 5432,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE ||'konga_database',
    // schema: process.env.DB_PG_SCHEMA ||'public',
    // poolSize: process.env.DB_POOLSIZE || 10,
    ssl: process.env.DB_SSL ? true : false // If set, assume it's true
  },
```

Below is .env file configuration

```
PORT=1337
NODE_ENV=production
KONGA_HOOK_TIMEOUT=120000
DB_ADAPTER=postgres
DB_URI=postgresql://localhost:5432/konga
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=XXXX
KONGA_LOG_LEVEL=info
TOKEN_SECRET=
```

kong and postgresql are already running on the AWS linux AMI 2 server on there respective ports i.e. 8443 & 5432

Please help us to prepare DB and start konga service. Also. let us know in case you need more info.

```
Node v: v12.19.0
NPM v: 6.14.8
```

Regards
Nitin G

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I overlooked it, but what version of PostreSQL are you using?

Konga is not able to support postgresql 12:

https://github.com/pantsel/konga/issues/487

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this?

.env

```
DB_URI=postgresql://userdb:passworddb@localhost:5432/kongadb
```

I tried on Postgresql 9.6
https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-postgresql-9-6-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Answer (score 0):

Konga has had issues with Postgresql >= 12 for a long time now. I just happened upon a modified docker image for Konga [here](https://github.com/pantsel/konga/issues/487#issuecomment-1442292331). The image name is `moago/konga_pg14`. I just tried it out today and it just works.

All I had to do was map my already existing .env file to the one in the container. Here is a snippet.

```
volumes:
  - type: bind
    source: .env
    target: /app/.env
```

Kindly give it a try and let me know how it goes :)